# Plot a cone in spherical co-ordinates

Tags: plotting, algebraic-manipulation, geometry, coordinate-transformation

As we all know in spherical coordinates a function `phi = π/3` gives us a cone. The cone makes an angle of `π/3` with the imagined `z`-axis. How do I type this formula into *Mathematica*?

Comment: `RevolutionPlot3D[3 z, {z, 0, -2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 Mesh -> None]`

Comment: Related cones on spheres: [Cone image refinement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235778/cone-image-refinement).

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`CoordinateTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoordinateTransform.html) to change coordinates to Cartesian and then use [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html) to make the plot.

```
cone[r_, θ_] := 
  Evaluate[CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, ϕ, θ}] /. ϕ -> π/4]
ParametricPlot3D[cone[r, θ], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2. π}]
```

This gives

[image: plot.png]